# jenkins terminates automatically due to a process "/var/tmp/bbb/bbb"

Tags: linux, jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins, continuous-deployment

I am using non-containerized jenkins on server. It gets terminated automatically each time I try to restart it.

Process which is killing jenkins is "/var/tmp/bbb/bbb". This process gets triggered by jenkins and even If I try to kill this process and restart jenkins service, jenkins again trigger this process which eventually happen to be a reason for termination of jenkins.

> /var/tmp/bbb/bbb

I've also searched on google but couldn't find anything useful. Please help.

[servers htop report here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kvOFJ.png)

Comment: Looks like some virus. It is better to recreate your virtual machine (or reinstall OS on hardware server) from scratch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your root crontab.

I found the same process, made investigation. My instance was using for mining with scripts in crontab.

These scripts stop processes, stop all security services and syslog, create new users, find ssh-keys, change iptables, etc.